# Visual Basic - Controlling various form elements

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, label

I have a project in mind with so many form controls(like 3 hundred labels), and I must change all of their texts.

So I want to do something like this

```
For i= 1 to 300
(Labeli).text = "xyz"
Next
```

I can't write and change all of the labels one by one so I need a way to change any label by using a number + "Label" so it becomes "Labeli".

Sorry for my english, I am waiting for your help, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
For i = 1 to 300
  CType(Me.Controls("Label" & i), Label).Text = "xyz"
Next
```

You will need to add recursion or flatten your label controls, if you have them nested.

Comment: Me.Controls("Label" & i)

 this was what I was looking for thanks :)